# TFOOT at the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I wonder on how to put the tfoot on the bottom of the page and it should remain there during page scroll. I tried putting it in a separate table but it's not aligning with the tbody from the other table because it's dynamic. 
I know it's possible with stickyheaders but it doesn't work with tfoot. Any idea? Can CSS handle this?

Comment: tfoot is a **table foot**, it does not stand for a **page** foot.

Comment: Yeah i know that. Well, it is not possible. Is it?

Comment: time to rethink your use of tables....they don't mesh well with positioning

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want a footer for a page, you could use:

### html

```
<footer class="global-footer"></footer>
```

### css

```
.global-footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1em
}
```

HOWEVER --- there are tons of cross-browser issues to worry about, now more than ever. Fixed headers and footers are a mess in safari and the large new tablets coming out (12/2013) there are some solutions but not great ones...

Comment: add a class global-footer in your tfoot <tfoot class='global-footer'></tfoot>

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use a `div`

```
<div style="width:100%;position:fixed;bottom:0">some footer content</div>
```

Comment: like i said, i need tfoot to align to the table cells. this method will now let tfoot align